# Require Css Important Property

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, requirejs, requirecss

```
/* Automaton Version 2.0.0*/

define([
'css!bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min',
'css!bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min',
'css!bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min',
'css!bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-csp',
'css!bower_components/animate.css/animate.min',
'css!bower_components/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.css',
'css!bower_components/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch-bootstrap.css',
'css!bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css',
'css!bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min',
'css!bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min',
'css!assets/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke',
'css!assets/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/helper',
'css!assets/css/style',
'css!assets/css/custom',
'css!bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min'


], function() {
$app.info("CSS file Loaded");
return true;
});
```

This is the code I use for my application, but while importing one css overwrites other randomly, How to specify important property over here

Comment: CSS is executed in the order it is downloaded, last file being the winner... there is no randomness at all. Just order them so the css you want most is at the bottom.

Comment: try putting `css!assets/css/custom` as the last.